# Which countries provide the parameters for their national height reference model in the AIP?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, aeronautical-information

There is a standard in Annex 15 1.2.2.3 "When a geoid model other than the EGM-96 model is used, a description of the model used, including the parameters required for height transformation between the model and EGM-96, shall be provided in the Aeronautical Information Publication (AIP)". According to this provision, I could not find any Country which published the parameters required for height transformation between the model and EGM-96.

For example: Canada uses the Canadian Geodetic Vertical Datum 1928 (CGVD28) as its vertical reference system. The Canadian Gravimetric Geoid 2000 (CGG2000) is the scientific model of the geoid for North America.

I believe this is important for Aviation users. I want to ask if there is any country which is trying to establish the parameters in the AIP?

Comment: For AIP Canada uses the NAD 83 which is deemed equivalent to WGS 84, with a maximum vertical difference of 1 m in the area covered by Canada AIP (less than 1% of geoids maximal undulation). As this difference is below GNSS accuracy or any other civil "instantaneous" positioning system, it shouldn't interfere in navigation. See the [geoid undulation comparison for Montréal](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeoidEval?input=45.5087+-73.554&option=Submit) for several gravitational models.

Comment: @mins NAD83 / WGS84 describes the ellipsoid, EGM-96 describes the geoid with respect to the WGS84 ellipsoid. The vertical datum in the AIP is sea level (geoid), which is defined by EGM-96 but also by other geoid models. Hence the choice of geoid model is important. For example if the difference is 1 metre, on a 3 degree glideslope that is a horizontal displacement of 20 meters. This is important for GBAS approaches.

Comment: @DeltaLima: Under your supervision: NAD83 and WGS84 ellipsoids are nearly identical, so we can get AMSL (orthometric) altitude differences by looking at the geoid height (undulation) differences. CGVD28 reference surface is not a geoid, but HT2.0 hybrid geoid is an approximation at 5 cm. At Montréal, for [HT2.0](http://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/tools-outils/gpsh.php?locale=en#), N = -30.771 and for [EGM96](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeoidEval?input=45.5087+-73.554&option=Submit), N = -31.5426. The difference is 77 cm which is still small compared to GBAS accuracy of ~1 m.